# Fine Uploader ie9 upload fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, fine-uploader

I have a strange issue with fine uploader (3.0) it works on each and every browser except for ie9.

There is no js error, it just uploads a 0byte fails.
I'm using the valums php and it fails here:

```
$realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);
        //This results in an error in ie9
        if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
            return false;
        }
```

if I comment the return it creates a 0 bytes file, it looks like ie9 is not sending any data.
Do anyone of you have any idea of what could be the issue?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

As required client code:

```
if($('#fine-uploader_main').length > 0){

        var method = $('#fine-uploader_main_method').val();
        var fileCount = 0;
        $('#fine-uploader_main').fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: base_url+"ajax/"+method,//base_url+'ajax/upload_afile/can_id/'+$('#fine-uploader-can_id').val(),
            },
            text: {
                uploadButton: '<i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload'
            },
            template: '<div class="qq-uploader span12">' +
                  '<pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></pre>' +
                  '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-success" style="width: auto;">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                  '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                  '<ul class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></ul>' +
                '</div>',
            classes: {
                success: 'alert alert-success',
                fail: 'alert alert-error'
            }
        }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName,response) {
            if(response.success==true){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", url: base_url+"ajax/"+method+"_return",data:"filename="+response.filename,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#uploader_container").hide();
                        $("#uploader_success").html(html).show();
                        $("#fileupload-check").removeClass('required');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //console.log(response);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: If you have an issue with IE why don't you post the client side code?

Comment: The client-side code will not help debug this issue.  What you need to do is set the debug option to true and post the contents of your javascript console after the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you are simply not handling Multipart Encoded requests, which are sent only by IE9 and earlier by default in 3.0.  Your server-side code must properly handle these requests to support IE9 and earlier, along with Android 2.3.x.

Comment: Yes that was is it. If anyone else stumble upon this question there is a multipart upload example on the fine uploader repository. Thank you.